# Spivak's Calculus Q 1-20

Tags: calculus, inequality

Question 1-20: Prove that if $|x-x_0| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|y-y_0| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ then $|(x+y) - (x_0 + y_0)| < \epsilon$ and $|(x-y) - (x_0 - y_0)| < \epsilon$.**

I have proven the first inequality by expanding the absolute value into $x_0 - 
\frac{\epsilon}{2} < x < x_0 + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and similarily for $y$. Then, I concatenated both of the inequalities and simplified to end up with the desired inequality $|(x-y) - (x_0 - y_0)| < \epsilon$.

How do I do the same for part two of this question (**)?

I tried to assume that $\epsilon > 0$ but that isn't a given. By assuming $\epsilon > 0$ I ended up that $|(x-y) - (x_0 - y_0)| < 0 < \epsilon$, the desired conclusion. How can I circumvent this $\epsilon > 0$ issue?

Edit: The last line is utter bupkis, considering the absolute value forces  $(x-y) - (x_0 - y_0) > 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Triangle Inequality:
$$
|(x+y)-(x_0+y_0)|\leq |x-x_0|+|y-y_0| < 2\cdot \varepsilon/2 = \varepsilon
$$
$$
|(x-y)-(x_0-y_0)|\leq |x-x_0|+|-y+y_0| < 2\cdot \varepsilon/2 = \varepsilon
$$

Comment: Ah! That pesky negative sign!

Comment: death by negative is the number one killer of calculus students